# How to write presto query output to s3 on emr cluster?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, presto

I want to write Presto query output from EMR cluster to S3 location. I performing below command but it is not working. Do I need to change any configs on EMR cluster for this?

```
INSERT INTO DIRECTORY 's3n://test-bucket/manoj/presto-query-output/' 
select logdate from hive.core.candidates_orc_hr  s WHERE logdate = '2022-05-12' AND loghour = '21';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below approach:

CREATE SCHEMA test_hive.s3_write WITH (location = 's3a://parquet-test-bucket/');

CREATE TABLE test_hive.s3_write.my_table
WITH (format = 'PARQUET')
AS select logdate from hive.core.candidates_orc_hr  s WHERE logdate = '2022-05-12' AND loghour = '21';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).